# adding radiobutton inside dojo enhanced grid programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I want to add the radio button for each row. I was searching for some online dojo examples to add radio buttons programmatically but could not find the solution. Please suggest how can I add radio button before column1 of each row every time when ever I add a new row.
Below is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/59/

Sample code:

```
    /*create a new grid*/
    var grid = new DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'
    });

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();

    var id = 2;

    var button = new Button({
        onClick: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
            store.newItem({
                id: id,
                col2: "col2-" + id,
                col3: "col3-" + id,
                col4: "col4-" + id
            });
            id++;
        }
    }, "addRow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest way I can think of is to just change your layout and add a radio selector (dojox/grid/_RadioSelector) to the layout.

Something like

```
var layout = [
    { type: "dojox.grid._RadioSelector"},
    [{
        'name': 'Column 1',
            'field': 'id',
            'width': '100px'
    }, {
        'name': 'Column 2',
            'field': 'col2',
            'width': '100px'
    }, {
        'name': 'Column 3',
            'field': 'col3',
            'width': '200px'
    }, {
        'name': 'Column 4',
            'field': 'col4',
            'width': '150px'
    }]
];
```

I've update your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/68/) to show you how it's done.

Comment: Its working in fiddle , but when i run the same example on my local tomcat server, its not showing the radio buttons. Please see the image in the above edited post. I'm using dojo1.9. Thanks @Richard.

Comment: Can you post some of your code here? It's a bit hard to debug if I can't see the code so that I can try to figure out what's happening

Comment: As mentioned i'm using dojo1.9 and its the same code you mentioned in http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/68/ , i copied  and pasted in my jsp page and tried to run on local tomcat server. Its not showing any console error messages but even not showing the radio buttons. U can see the output of the same in the image i pasted in the original above post.Its showing some kind of square boxes and i cannot select them. The code i used is same as http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/68/ but its working perfectly in fiddle but not when run on local server. Please suggest do i need to add any library file?

Comment: Well in that fiddle, the external resources loaded include quite a few css files (e.g., dojo.css, claro.css, Grid.css, etc). Do you have all of those css files loaded? If I were to guess though, I'd bet it's that you don't have claro.css loaded

Comment: i have all the required files imported. I have claro.css too. i cross verified it. Appreciate your effort. Richard if i'm not rude can you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035971/dojo-combo-box-dropdown-list-to-load-dynamic-data-inside-dojo-grid , i'm looking for that answer. @Richard. Thanks.

Comment: Can you host your jsp page somewhere and post a link to it? It's too hard to guess out of the blue on what your problem is.